# QuickBlox JavaScript SDK: No incoming Call

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I'm developing an application (JavaScript) using QuickBlox. I was able to initialize QB, connect to chat session and place call successfully but **onCallListener** wasn't getting any incoming call.

My complete code is given bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var mediaParams = {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                options: {
                    muted: true,
                    mirror: false
                },
                elemId: 'LocalVideo'
            };

            var CONFIG = {
                webrtc: {
                    answerTimeInterval: 60, // Max answer time after that the 'QB.webrtc.onUserNotAnswerListener' callback will be fired.
                    dialingTimeInterval: 5,  // The interval between call requests produced by session.call(extension)
                    disconnectTimeInterval: 30 // If an opponent lost a connection then after this time the caller will now about it via 'QB.webrtc.onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener' callback.
                }
            };

            var call = $('#callingSignal')[0];
            var ring = $('#ringtoneSignal')[0];
            var btnCall = $("#btn-Call");

            btnCall.prop("value", "Initialing");
            btnCall.prop('disabled', true);

            QB.init(app_id, 'api_key', 'api_secret', CONFIG);
            QB.createSession({
                login: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }, function (err, res) {

                if (res) {

                    QB.chat.connect({
                        userId: 12345678,
                        password: 'password'
                    }, function (err, roster) {

                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Chat connection error: " + err);
                            return false;
                        } else {

                            console.log("QB is ready");
                            btnCall.prop('disabled', false);
                            btnCall.prop('enabled', true);
                            btnCall.prop("value", "Call Now");
                            console.log(QB);

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("QB session creation error: " + err);
                    return false;
                }

            });

            btnCall.click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var searchIDs = $(".callee input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                    return parseInt($(this).val());
                }).get();

                console.log(searchIDs.length);

                if (searchIDs.length < 1) {
                    console.log("Caller ID wasn't provided");
                    return false;
                }

                console.log("Calling: " + searchIDs);

                var session = QB.webrtc.createNewSession(searchIDs, QB.webrtc.CallType.VIDEO);
                session.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function (err, stream) {
                    if (err) {
                        alert("Without media access, it's not possible to continue calling: " + err);
                        window.location = "/";
                    } else {
                        session.call(searchIDs, function (error) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log("Call establishment error: " + error);
                            } else {
                                btnCall.prop("value", "Calling");
                                btnCall.prop('disabled', true);
                                call.play();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });


            });

            QB.webrtc.onCallListener = function onCallListener(session, extension) {
                console.log("Incoming Call");
                console.log(session);
                console.log(extension);
                session.accept(extension);
            };

            QB.webrtc.onUserNotAnswerListener = function onUserNotAnswerListener(session, userId) {
                call.pause();
                var naemsg = "Sorry, <strong>" + Databases[userId] + "</strong> did't pick the call!";
                showErrorModal(naemsg);
                btnCall.prop('disabled', false);
                btnCall.prop('enabled', true);
                btnCall.prop("value", "Call Now");
            };

            QB.webrtc.onAcceptCallListener = function onAcceptCallListener(session, userId, extension) {
                console.log(Databases[userId] + " Call answered")
            };

            QB.webrtc.onRemoteStreamListener = function onRemoteStreamListener(session, userID, remoteStream) {
                // attach the remote stream to DOM element
                session.attachMediaStream('MainVideo', remoteStream);
                $("#MainVideo").prop("controls", true);
                btnCall.prop('disabled', false);
                btnCall.prop('enabled', true);
                btnCall.prop("value", "Call Now");
            };

            QB.chat.onDisconnectedListener = function onDisconnectedListener() {
                showErrorModal("Session disconnected. Please reload the page.");
                btnCall.prop('disabled', false);
                btnCall.prop('enabled', true);
                btnCall.prop("value", "Call Now");
            };

            QB.webrtc.onSessionCloseListener = function onSessionCloseListener(session) {
                console.log('onSessionCloseListener: ' + session);
            };

            QB.webrtc.onUpdateCallListener = function onUpdateCallListener(session, userId, extension) {
                console.log("Call updater")
            };

            QB.webrtc.onRejectCallListener = function onRejectCallListener(session, userId, extension) {
                showErrorModal("Sorry, <strong>" + Databases[userId] + "</strong> rejected your call!");
            };

            QB.webrtc.onStopCallListener = function onStopCallListener(session, userId, extension) {
                console.log("Called Stopped");
                btnCall.prop('disabled', false);
                btnCall.prop('enabled', true);
                btnCall.prop("value", "Call Now");
            };

            QB.webrtc.onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener = function onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener(session, userID, connectionState) {
                console.group('onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener.');
                console.log('UserID: ' + userID);
                console.log('Session: ' + session);
                console.log('Сonnection state: ' + connectionState);
                console.groupEnd();


                if (connectionState === QB.webrtc.SessionConnectionState.CONNECTING) {
                    console.log("Connecting")
                }

                if (connectionState === QB.webrtc.SessionConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                    console.log("Connected")
                }

                if (connectionState === QB.webrtc.SessionConnectionState.COMPLETED) {
                    console.log("Completed")
                }

                if (connectionState === QB.webrtc.SessionConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
                    console.log("Discinnected")
                }

                if (connectionState === QB.webrtc.SessionConnectionState.CLOSED) {
                    console.log("Closed")
                }
            };


        });

        function showErrorModal(errorMsg) {
            var errorModal = $('.errorModal');
            $('.errorModalMsg').html(errorMsg);
            errorModal.modal();
        }
    </script>
```

I wasn't get such error message after celling in console window. But other logged in user didn't receive any call

Console log is here:

```
[QBWebRTC]: RTCPeerConnection init. userID: 12345678, sessionID: 42681376-cdd0-4d7e-b260-a5dab33441c3, type: offer
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: getAndSetLocalSessionDescription success
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: _startDialingTimer, dialingTimeInterval: 5000
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: _dialingCallback, answerTimeInterval: 0
quickblox.min.js:6 Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('0') is not a valid name.
...
...
...

[QBWebRTC]: _dialingCallback, answerTimeInterval: 60000
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: _clearDialingTimer
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: Answer timeout callback for session 42681376-cdd0-4d7e-b260-a5dab33441c3 for user 10431702
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: All peer connections closed: true
(index):244 onSessionCloseListener: ID: 42681376-cdd0-4d7e-b260-a5dab33441c3, initiatorID:  12345678, opponentsIDs: 12345678, state: 2, callType: 1
quickblox.min.js:3 [QBWebRTC]: onIceConnectionStateCallback: closed
(index):263 onSessionConnectionStateChangedListener.
(index):264 UserID: 12345678
(index):265 Session: ID: 42681376-cdd0-4d7e-b260-a5dab33441c3, initiatorID:  10311194, opponentsIDs: 10431702, state: 5, callType: 1
(index):266 Сonnection state: 5
(index):287 Closed
```

Only error message I got was

> quickblox.min.js:6 Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute
>   'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('0') is not a
>   valid name..

I couldn't get why onCallListener didn't get any response in Callee end.

Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: you need to add a incoming pop in onCallListener event.

$(ui.modal.income_call).modal('show'); like this. 
It is given in a quickblox documentation.

Comment: Negative. I've console log there, If any call comes, console should print those log message.

Comment: Hi did you have any solution?

Comment: No. Even support team couldn't help me.